# BeautifultSoup Python get content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I don't usually play with BeautifulSoup in Python so I am struggling to find the value 8.133,00 that matches with the Ibex 35 in the web page: https://es.investing.com/indices/indices-futures
So far I am getting all the info of the page, but I can't filter to get that value:

```
site = 'https://es.investing.com/indices/indices-futures'
hardware = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/106.0'}
request = Request(site,headers=hardware)
page = urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I appreciate a hand to get that value.
Regards

Comment: investing.com seems to be using an anti-scraping algorithm.

Comment: Yes, it has. So I drop it. Thank you

Comment: Don't give up so easily, mate...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of getting that bit of information - a dataframe with all the info in that table containing IBEX 35, DAX, and so on, you can then slice that dataframe as you wish.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(disableCloudflareV1=True)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

url = 'https://es.investing.com/indices/indices-futures'
r = scraper.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.select_one('table[class="datatable_table__D_jso quotes-box_table__nndS2 datatable_table--mobile-basic__W2ilt"]')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   IBEX 35derived  8.098,10    -3510   -0,43%  NaN
1   US 500derived   3.991,90    355 +0,90%  NaN
2   US Tech 100derived  11.802,20   1962    +1,69%  NaN
3   Dow Jones   33.747,86   3249    +0,10%  NaN
4   DAXderived  14.224,86   7877    +0,56%  NaN
5   Índice dólarderived 106255  -1837   -1,70%  NaN
6   Índice euroderived  11404   89  +0,79%  NaN
```

See https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/